# Comparing Date on SAS

Tags: date, sas

I have been stuck with this issue, I might being doing something wrong. Could someone help me please

I try to compare this date

The Code is below

```
data final_&SEMterm.;
set final_&i;
if EffdtAcadPlan < CENSUSSATE THEN Flag ="YES";
ELSE Flag ="N0";
run;
```

[image]

[image]

This is in the loop.

I think Flag should Be "NO" SINCE 20161201 NOT < 20160906, but somehow showing "YES"

I can not figure out why Could you help me please.

Comment: Are you sure you are browsing the same dataset as the SAS data step code is writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue cannot be replicated. You are either

- looking at the wrong file
- looking at the wrong code
- code didn't run for some reason and log indicates a partial (incomplete/wrong file) is present.

You can verify this by starting in a clean session and not using macro variables.

This example shows the code will work correctly:

```
data have;

effdtAcadPlan = '01Dec2016'd;
censussate = '06Sep2016'd;


format effdtAcadPlan censussate yymmddn8.;

if EffdtAcadPlan < CENSUSSATE THEN Flag ="YES";
ELSE Flag ="N0";

put _all_;

run;

proc print data=have;
run;
```

You can add the `put _all_;` (see line below with asterisks) in your code to check the log to see that your code is working and then isolate the source of the issue.

log:

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 68         
 69         data have;
 70         
 71         effdtAcadPlan = '01Dec2016'd;
 72         censussate = '06Sep2016'd;
 73         
 74         
 75         format effdtAcadPlan censussate yymmddn8.;
 76         
 77         if EffdtAcadPlan < CENSUSSATE THEN Flag ="YES";
 78         ELSE Flag ="N0";
 79         
 80         put _all_;
 81         
 82         run;
 
 **effdtAcadPlan=20161201 censussate=20160906 Flag=N0 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1**
 NOTE: The data set WORK.HAVE has 1 observations and 3 variables.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       user cpu time       0.01 seconds
       system cpu time     0.00 seconds
       memory              666.43k
       OS Memory           24740.00k
       Timestamp           02/02/2021 10:11:00 PM
       Step Count                        38  Switch Count  2
       Page Faults                       0
       Page Reclaims                     141
       Page Swaps                        0
       Voluntary Context Switches        10
       Involuntary Context Switches      0
       Block Input Operations            0
       Block Output Operations           264
```